# Assets of childtheme missing in pre-built docker - Shopware 6.4 shop

Tags: docker, shopware6

We are hosting a Shop via docker and pre build the image with

```
CI=1 SHOPWARE_SKIP_THEME_COMPILE=true PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true DATABASE_URL= bin/build-storefront.sh
```

in build container without a database being available and copy everything to the production container.

```
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data --from=build /var/www .
```

When starting the production container we compile the theme:

```
bin/console theme:dump
bin/console theme:compile --keep-assets || true
```

This mostly works but we found out that `public/bundles/ourchildthme/assets` is missing, while icon und logo folders are here.

We tried to execute

```
bin/console assets:install
```

manually in the docker production container, but it is still not copied.

If we execute `bin/build.sh` it works, but of course this is not the idea of the pre-build docker container.

- In which part of the process should this asset folder be generated?
- Where to put it in the process - in the pre-building or when starting the container?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75670136/build-administration-in-shopware-6-without-database-and-without-var-plugins-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake seems `--keep-assets`

Without this, it works:

`bin/console theme:compile || true`