# build-administration in Shopware 6 without database and without var/plugins.json

Tags: continuous-integration, shopware6

We are pre-building a docker image for our Shopware in the CI pipeline. During the build, no database is available.

Now we saw that the administration for custom plugins is not built:

During

```
CI=1 PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true DATABASE_URL= bin/build-administration.sh
```

This is printed:

```
#20 0.512 + /var/www/bin/ci bundle:dump
#20 2.309 Warning: Failed to load apps. Loading apps from local. Message: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for _placeholder.test failed: Name or service not known
#20 2.312
```

Which makes sense, as there is no database.

One solution would be to add the `var/plugins.json` to the git repository to make the build work.

Is this the only solution or is there some "smarter" way, to generate the `plugins.json` with all the plugins which are found in the filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to dneustadt's answer:

It is additionally important to use `SHOPWARE_SKIP_BUNDLE_DUMP`. Otherwise *some* of the plugins will be dumped to the `plugins.json` while custom plugins are missing.

So

- commit the `var/plugins.json` to the git
- use

  ```
  CI=1 SHOPWARE_SKIP_BUNDLE_DUMP=true PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true DATABASE_URL= bin/build-administration.sh
  CI=1 SHOPWARE_SKIP_BUNDLE_DUMP=true SHOPWARE_SKIP_THEME_COMPILE=true PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true DATABASE_URL= bin/build-storefront.sh
  ```

  to build

Answer (score 1):

The database connection is needed to determine whether a plugin is installed and activated through the data stored in the `plugin` table. Hence why the mere existence of the plugin in the filesystem is not a sufficient indicator. Adding the `plugin.json` manually is probably your best bet.

Comment: Actually I would be okay with an --all-plugins option, so it would not care about which plugins are installed and we assume that just all plugins which are present should be build. Unfortunately such an option does not exist and I am not possible if it is possible. maybe it is, because bundle:dump seems to dump *some* plugins, but not those in `custom/plugins` (and maybe we are doing it wrong and should put our plugins in `custom/static-plugins`)

Comment: Can you confirm that composer based plugins are added to plugin.json even though there is no database connected? That would be a good solution then and we just would need to register them as `static-plugins` - feel free to clarify in your answer :-)